# Unity: How to change quality of texture2d with script

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d

I created a 2 by 2 texture and painted a pixel (0,0) in black. It turned out something like this: [image]
 But I wanted to get a texture like this:
[image].
 How can I do this?

Comment: `texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point` https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FilterMode.html

Comment: @LeoBartkus you should make this an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point
```

docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FilterMode.html